# fitbit tag axe request

Tags: discussion

I would like to suggest removing the fitbit tag...
Reasons:
-It doesn't have any relation to Ubuntu,

-Fitbit is a company and should be kept off-topic here

Please remove it. *feel free to leave comments*

Comment: What if I own a fitbit and can't get it to work on Ubuntu, then the tag would be very useful to me as it would attract other who know about fitbit on Ubuntu.

Comment: I would like to add here, many user think anything that is not Ubuntu specific is off topic, it is not, if you want to run something on or use any device with Ubuntu, then it is on topic.

Answer (score 10):

Fitbit is also the name of a line of products. I took a look at the question with the tag and it seems like an on-topic question. Given that the question specifically relates to the product, it seems like an appropriate tag.

And besides, when it comes to precedent, we have lots of tags with company names:

- [hp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp)
- [dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell)
- [canon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/canon)
- *etc...*